# How to filter reserved words in parser combinators?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I am using Scala's Parser Combinator framework, extending the `RegexParsers` class. I have an `identifier` token which starts with a letter and can contain alphabet characters, dashes, underscores and digits, as long as it is not one of the reserved words. I tried to use the parser's `not()` to function to stop reserved words from being used, however it is also matching identifiers which are prefixed with a reserved word.

```
def reserved = "and" | "or"

def identifier: Parser[String] = not(reserved) ~> """[a-zA-Z][\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*""".r
```

However, when I tried to parse an identifier like `and-today` I get an error saying `Expected Failure`.

How do I only filter reserved words if they are a full match of the token and not just a prefix?

Also is there a way to improve the error reporting in this case when using `not()`? In other cases I get the regular expression that the parser is expecting, but in this case it just says `Failure` without any details.

Comment: Is it absolutely required that you use regex? You can use combine pattern matching and comparison params like `.equalsIgnoreCase` to get the desired result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by combine pattern matching. Yes the token has to match the regular expression, apart from a few reserved words (which I want to keep out of the regex). It is quite a substantial parser making use of regex in various other places. Maxim's solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filterWithError` both to filter out the reserved words and to customize the error message like this:

```
    val reservedWords = HashSet("and", "or")

    val idRegex= """[a-zA-Z][\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*""".r

    val identifier = Parser(input =>
      idRegex(input).filterWithError(
        !reservedWords.contains(_),
        reservedWord => s"YOUR ERROR MESSAGE FOR $reservedWord",
        input
      )
    )
```